# Android - Using SpannableStringBuilder for per character color change

Tags: android, spannablestring

Heyo, I'm using `SpannableStringBuilder` to change a word's each character color. This is how I use it :

```
SpannableStringBuilder specialSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder();

specialSpan.append(context.getResources().getString(R.string.asdf));

specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)), 0, 0, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple)), 1, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)), 2, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green)), 3, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

userSpecialText.setText(specialSpan);
```

The problem is, the `TextView`'s color doesn't change. Am I missing something here?

Update :

I'm using this other Spannable string builder which works for adding `Emojis`

```
for (String part :
partofContent){
if (part.contains(":")){
    int firstEq = sb.length();
    Typeface font = FontCache.getTypeface("emojione-android.ttf", context);
    String convertPart = Emojione.shortnameToUnicode(part, true);
    sb.append(convertPart + " ");
    int lastEq = sb.length();
    sb.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), firstEq, lastEq, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    } else {
    sb.append(part + " ");
    }
}
```

And to change the color of a detected user Alias

```
int aliasStart = sb.length();
sb.append("@" + alias + " ");
int aliasEnd = sb.length();

sb.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan("@" + alias + " "), aliasStart, aliasEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.miBlue)), aliasStart, aliasEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), aliasStart, aliasEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

That worked well too, and it uses the same `ForegroundColorSpan` in `setSpan()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like This

```
SpannableStringBuilder specialSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder();

specialSpan.append(context.getResources().getString(R.string.asdf));

 specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)), 0, 1,   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple)), 1, 2,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)), 2, 3,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 specialSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green)), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

userSpecialText.setText(specialSpan);
```

You're specifing same for both start and end that means you're specifying a span of length 0, not a span of length 1.

[image]

Comment: I have already try it and than answer it,it was perfect working.

Comment: @ Kevin Murvie:Try to change flag-->> Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE to "0" (Zero)

Comment: Tried using 0, still not working.. Btw I am writing those code inside a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, should I place it inside the `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: @KevinMurvie yes,you can write `onBindViewHolder` and always `setText` on this method.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( is there something else I am missing? That's on an empty activity right?

Comment: Umm.. It's.. 2k lines for adapter and 354 lines for `Fragment`.. Can I just post parts where it is needed??

Comment: @KevinMurvie, yes please I will try ,